# How to save custom value as template parameter/field?

Tags: templates

Normal code to add some field to the template is:

```
<field name="examplevalue" type="text" default="" label="Example value" description="" />
```

I need something like this but dynamicly, because of this needs i imported in backend of my template 1 js file which is: admin.js, i insert in my control group a new span element:

```
$('#attrib-example-control-group').append('<span id="addnewvalue">add new value</span>');
```

Then i added a new action for this button also trough admin.js:

```
$('#addnewvalue').on('click', function () {
    $('#attrib-example-control-group').append('<div class="control-group">\n\
        Example value: <input type="text" name="newexamplevalue" id="newexamplevalue" />\n\
    </div>'); 
});
```

What i tried:

1. Give standard xml parameter for template fields `<field>`
2. Tried to copy html output of already existing values, renamed it and tried to save

I have now method how i add this fields, but my problem is how to save it successful?

Comment: Are you adding your element under `<fields name="params">`?

Comment: I tried so, but nothing was saved.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you noticed, but fields have a specific naming convention, like:

```
jform[params][sitetitle]
```

But this will anyway not do it.

Joomla has a security mechanism in `JControllerForm::save()`.

```
    // Test whether the data is valid.
    $validData = $model->validate($form, $data);
```

The posted data will be checked / validated against the XML with fields / parameters.  Since you have not defined your field, it will be removed.

Have a look at the [Repeatable form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type).